# Connect Raspberry Pi 3 with some Arduinos UNO Wifi

Tags: wifi

Is it possible to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 with a network of Arduino UNO Wifi, only use Wifi communication?

Or for example if I have Arduinos UNO and I want to conect with Raspberry, is more easy use example the ESP8266 or other like Xbee or NRF24L01.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to connect Raspberry Pi 3 and Arduino with WiFi shield to the same WiFi network.

It is also common to use ESP8266 as a "WiFi Arduino" but it is more limited in regards of In/Out ports.

Comment: But is the same when I used Arduino Uno Wifi?

Comment: Can you be more precise, I don't understand!

Comment: Because I have the Arduino Uno Wifi, that bring the ESP8266 incorporated

Comment: Perhaps you can point to the product you have, facts rules!

Comment: @Omrv18 please be so kind to provide all required details in the question itself (you can edit it) and not bit by bit via comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'Arduino Uno WiFi' is a good board from Arduino.org. I did write [an unofficial documentation](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-firmware-wifilink/blob/ota/UNOWIFI_DEV_ED.md) for it with links to official documentation archive.

*I can't add this as comment, so moderators do with it what you want.*